# Any forena alternatives to consider for creating a (line) chart in Drupal (using a mysql data source)?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, charts

I have a mysql database locally that I would like to use to create a line chart in Drupal.

Which module should I use? I found the [Forena](http://drupal.org/project/forena) module, but the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) requires expertise.

What I am trying to do is to connect to mysql database and present live data on a graph, something similar to this [sample line chart created with forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2362447#LineGraph).

Comment: You could consider writing a small module which connects to your DB, retrives data, and create a block where you insert a chart (using google charts or highcharts...) by outputing a JS array and the chart init ? See http://www.webomelette.com/drupal-7-connect-other-external-database, https://www.drupal.org/node/18429, http://kahthong.com/2013/06/create-your-own-custom-drupal-block-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

About a year ago I was in a similar position regarding, and also thought something like "... the documentation requires expertise".

In the meantime I've contributed 2 types of documentation related forena enhancements (due to which I was promoted to a forena co-maintainer also):

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

Apart from these documentation enhancements, the newest 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Here are some variations of the **mysql database locally** part in the questions:

1. Using a **SQLite** instead of MySQL database: the Forena samples actually get shipped including a (Tiny) SQLite database. Go check it out in the [demo site](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/samples): the data shown there are data contained in the sampledb, which is in SQLite format.
2. Forena comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

Enough reasons for considering giving forena a (new) try? While doing so, use it's issue queue for any type of support/docu requests you may have.